# Why subclass method isn't called?

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism

I have problem with subclassing and using methods.

I create an instance of class `B` and store it as a pointer to `A`. But when I use the pointer to call the overloaded method, the output is "A" not "B". Why?

This works in other languages, what am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    void f() {
        cout << "A";
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void f() {
        cout << "B";
    }
};

int main() {
    A *a = new B();
    a->f();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: declare A's `f()` method virtual. for to postpone  binging at runtime. Otherwise static binging for

Comment: yeah because it's not virtual

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`f()` needs to be declared `virtual` in the base class A:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void f() {
        cout << "A";
    }
};
```

The other languages you already worked with may default to virtual methods, but C++ doesn't (don't pay for what you don't use: virtual methods incur an indirection when calling them which means they are slightly slower than normal method calls).

By adding `virtual`, binding will be postponed to runtime (called [dynamic binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch)) and which `f()` function call will be decided on the *type of the value*.

Because you have not declared function `f()` as virtual, binding is static (at compilation time) and will use the *type of variable* (but not value) to determine which `f()` to call. So in your present code statment `a->f();` calls the `A` class's `f()` because `a` is pointer to the `A` class.

Answer (score 6):

In order to achieve polymorphic behavior, the method of the base class must be `virtual`.

So in `class A` you need to change `void f()` to `virtual void f()`.

Answer (score 2):

The function must be declared `virtual` to be able to override it:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    virtual void f() {// Here you must define the virtual.
        cout << "A";
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    virtual void f() { //Here the "virtual" is optional, but a good practice
        cout << "B";
    }
};

int main() {
    A *a = new B();
    a->f();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When a subclass provides the implementation of a method that is already defined in the base class, it's [**method overriding**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding) not overloading.

Answer (score 0):

You may face this problem when having not a pointers to the base class, but the actual instances of it *(not applicable to the example in this question)*

In my case, I had a class `Token` and its subclass `Word`:

```
class Token {
   public: virtual string toString() { ... }
}
class Word: public Token {
   public: string toString() { ... }
}
```

Storing them in `std::map<string, Token>` and retrieving from it I expected to call `Word::toString()` in code like this:

```
std::map<string, Token> words;
words.insert("test", Word(...));
words["test"].toString();
```

instead I called `Token::toString()` every time.

**Solution:** to use pointers like this `std::map<string, Token*>` and treat all instances as pointers
(TBH, I hate pointers already)